# Display function result into label text with StringVar?

Tags: python, string, tkinter, label

I am trying to get the result of my function to display onto the label, and then update every time that i call the function again by clicking my button.

I have tried StringVar but I do not think that I am using it correctly as I keep getting errors when trying to define the StringVar and set it to the result.  I also get errors when using 'textvariable' as a label option.

```
from random import choice
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import StringVar

items = ['Helm','Chest','Legs','Boots','Gloves']
droppeditem = StringVar()

def click():
    droppeditem.set(choice(items))


main = tk.Tk()
main.geometry("100x100")

button = tk.Button(main, command=click)
button.place(width=30, height=30, x=0, y=0)
label = tk.Label(main, textvariable=droppeditem)
label.place(relx=.5, rely=.5)

main.mainloop()
```

I would like for the item that was chosen by passing the randrange through my list, to be displayed in text on my label.

Tracebacks:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/manwe/PycharmProjects/GameStats/app.py", line 6, in <module>
    droppeditem = StringVar()
  File "C:\Users\manwe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 480, in __init__
    Variable.__init__(self, master, value, name)
  File "C:\Users\manwe\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 317, in __init__
    self._root = master._root()
AttributeError: 'NoneType' object has no attribute '_root'
```

Comment: Please show the version of the code where you tried to use StringVar.

Comment: Ok I have updated the code to that. I assume that I am just incorrectly using StringVar, but I don't understand what I should be doing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var1.set(click)
```

This tries to make the text in the StringVar be, not the result from the function, but the function itself.

```
button = tk.Button(main, command=click)
```

This calls the `click` function when the button is clicked, but the StringVar is not adjusted by the function. You want to use `.set` inside the function; and then to set the initial value, you can just `click()` outside instead of using `.set`.

Also, we have a more direct way to choose randomly from the list: with `random.choice`. Finally, `list` is a poor name for the list, because that name is already assigned at start-up (you can use it to create lists with, or to check if something is a list).

So:

```
from random import choice # instead of randrange
import tkinter as tk

items = ['Helm','Chest','Legs','Boots','Gloves']
var1 = StringVar() # maybe you can think of a better name for this, too? :)

def click():
    var1.set(choice(items))

click() # get a starting value
```

(If there are other errors, please include the full tracebacks in your post.)

Comment: Thank you for clarification! I have updated my program via those tips, however I still get a problem with the StringVar(). I have put the tracebacks in the op.